# How to have greyed out subsections in a table of contents frame?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I'm doing a beamer presentation with sections and subsections, and would like to remind the audience of the outline at some points (before some subsections). I would like all sections and subsections to be greyed out, except the one I'm about to enter.

At the moment, I'm using this:

```
\begin{frame}<beamer>
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection,hideothersubsections]
\end{frame}
```

But all subsections of currentsection are in normal font, not just the current one. I'd like to point out which of those subsections I'm about to enter, so I'd like the other ones to be greyed out.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Sorry if you already did this but in the manual p.100, this issue is explicitly handled. Does it not work for you?

Comment: Thanks! it wasn't on page 100 on my copy of the manual, but I double checked, and here it was, in section 10.5 (adding a table of contents). I didn't RTFM enough the first time.

Comment: No worries. We have been there countless of times. That's why I slightly pushed it :) By the way, section 10.5 is on page 100 for version 3.12, if not I would recommend you updating to the latest version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer was in section 10.5 of the manual (Adding a Table of Contents). You can specify different styles for the active and inactive subsections, using the `subsectionstyle` option:

```
\begin{frame}<beamer>
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection,hideothersubsections,subsectionstyle=show/shaded]
\end{frame}
```