# Customising shading in a table of contents

Tags: beamer

A [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37276/173305) addressed graying out inactive sections of a table of contents. I have a slightly more detailed question - if I want these inactive sections to be shaded, but I find the shading to make the text unreadable by my standards, is there a way I can choose a custom color for the shaded text? Thanks!

Edit: in response to comments, I'm providing a minimal example:

```
% titlepage-demo.tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\title{Some slides}
\date{05 November, 2018}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \large \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}

\begin{document}

%--- the titlepage frame -------------------------%
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}<beamer>
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

%--- the presentation begins here ----------------%

\section{FAT32}

\begin{frame}{A frame}
\end{frame}

\section{The models}

\begin{frame}{Another frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide us with the code that shows what you have tried. The code should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and be compilable.

Comment: @marmot I'm working with identical code to the previous question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37276/173305).

Comment: The problem is that the previous code is not a so-called minimal working example. To keep the posts accessible to everyone, and to avoid simple errors, the standard is to post a minimal document that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}`, can be compiled and shows what you have tried. You will also benefit from others posting such codes since then you do not have to guess which document class and packages are used.

Comment: @airbornemihir It is certainly possible to adjust the shading the table of contents. But without seeing a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows us which theme you are using, which default overlay specifications you have etc. it is really hard to guess what might or might not work for you.

Comment: @samcarter I added an example.

Comment: @airbornemihir You can adjust the opacity of the shaded sections by adding `\setbeamertemplate{section in toc shaded}[default][60]` to your preamble. The default value is 20, increase it to make it more visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the opacity of the shaded sections by changing the number in `\setbeamertemplate{section in toc shaded}[default][60]`. The default value is 20, increase it to make it more visible.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\title{Some slides}
\date{05 November, 2018}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \large \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc shaded}[default][60]

\begin{document}

%--- the titlepage frame -------------------------%
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}<beamer>
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

%--- the presentation begins here ----------------%

\section{FAT32}

\begin{frame}{A frame}
\end{frame}

\section{The models}

\begin{frame}{Another frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also `\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc shaded}[default][60]` etc. as required.